# XNA 3D Collision not working

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, collision-detection

I have made a game and I just updated the rendering to a new system which actually works. When I tried it out, I realized that the collision had been broken. I thought that there was something wrong with the new world matrices so I changed it to the one from the drawing, but that did not change anything. I am out of ideas and there are not any good sources on the web that told me how to do it. The following link is to my code without the edited collision method. If you could tell me what to do or even just a tip, that would be great. Thanks!

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a9sc9rcxahvukuf/Collision%20Help.txt

Comment: It really is legal to write classes in C#. Encouraged, even. To the point where most of us probably won't bother analyzing procedural code that doesn't follow C# naming conventions.

Comment: You should post the relevant part of your code, not a link to your whole project.

Comment: @pinckerman I have removed all the parts not essential to the topic. I have updated the link in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is being rendered in accordance with the transformations that are combined to create your effect.World, but your sphere (for that model) is not being influenced by these same transformations. So there is a disconnect between the transformations of your model & those of your sphere. Because of this, you can't be sure the sphere is positioned or scaled properly.

Although a sphere doesn't care about the model's rotational transformations, it does need the same scale & translational transformations that you give the model to render it.

There could be scale and/or translational transformations in your root or parent bones that are getting applied to the model via `CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo()` that are not making it to your sphere. For your sphere, you seem to be limiting it's transformations to a location variable... and that may not be enough.

One sure way to always have the correct transformations on your sphere is to transform it by the exact same set of matrices that you combine (and in the same order) to create your effect.World for rendering the model that goes along with the sphere.

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. I tried all different ways of doing it, but none of them worked. Some of them just removed the sphere completely completely. Could you show me how you would do it, because I am clearly doing something wrong. Thanks!